# prevent handlebars from parsing certain tags or character for html?

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I want to replace html file part with javaScript code. Need to use JS events. Since hbs only replaces text, I want to add a js script in html for this purpose. JS code is kept as string and passed as value and I want to execute that from html. **Using node js server side rendering with hbs.**

TS Code for handlebars parse:

```
const testScript = "\<script\> function displayDate(o) \{ let x = \"hello\"\;document.getElementById(\"demo\").innerHTML = o\;} </script>";


res.render("home", { testScript });
```

home html/hbs code:

```
 <div>

{{testScript}}

 </div>
```

result is:

```
<div>

&lt;script&gt; alert(&quot;Hello JavaScript!&quot;) &lt;/script&gt;

</div>
```

expected result is:

```
 <script>
function displayDate(o) {
    let x = "hello";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = o;
}
</script>


<p id="demo"></p>
```

**If could prevent handlebars from parsing certain tags as altered ones then the expected result could happen.**

Could not find a solution by searching using phrases mentioned in this question. So please mention me **a solution to keep the string as is for handlebar parsing.**

Is it possible to tell handlebars not to parse certain tags?

Comment: Try triple-trash `{{{testScript}}}`. Also, please remove the last line from your question as it's unnecessary.

Comment: Here's the reference of html escaping from their documentation https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#html-escaping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use triple-stash as per the official [documentation](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#html-escaping). The triple-trash does not escape output.

```
<div>
{{{testScript}}}
</div>
```